# React JS Вызов нескольких классов в ClassName

Tags: веб-программирование, reactjs, классы

Подскажите, как можно обратится сразу к нескольким классам используя `ClassName`.
На пример, есть: `<div className={classes.Section1}></div>`, как можно добавить класс `Section2` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вообще, способов несколько. Можно к примеру в переменной еще склеить классы через пробел перед помещением их в `className` компонента. К примеру:

```
const classs = classes.SectionOne + ' ' + classes.SectionTwo;
```

А потом просто прописать:

```
<div className={classs}></div>
```

А вообще, для этого дела я бы настоятельно рекомендовал к использованию утилиту для объединения имен классов. Лично я пользуюсь именно ей: [classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames). Сначала установите эту утилиту через команду:

```
npm install classnames --save
```

Какой получится код с использованием этой утилитки:

```
// импортируем утилиту в файл, где будет она использоваться
import classNames from 'classnames';

// затем просто используем в коде:
<div className={classNames(classes.SectionOne, classes.SectionTwo)}></div>
```

Возможно мой ответ похож на дубликат, но я решил пояснить почему и зачем. Если не хотите использовать стороннюю библиотеку, можно написать простую функцию, свою, которая будет принимать массив имен классов (строк) и на выходе отдавать строку, в которой все классы будут склеены через пробел как показано в этом ответе: [function works like the classNames module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49212876/5275890)

А вот хорошая ссылка на SO: [How to add multiple classes to a ReactJS Component](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34521797/5275890)

Comment: Спасибо за подробное объяснение!

Answer (score 4):

Это же конвертируется в обычную строку -

```
<div className={`${classes.Section1} ${classes.Section2}`}></div>
```

или

```
<div className={classes.Section1  + ' ' + classes.Section2}></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Можете написать вот так:

```
className={`${classes.Section1} ${classes.Section2}`}
```

Есть хорошая библиотека для работы с классами:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames

Answer (score 1):

className={[classes.Section1, classes.Section2].join(' ')}

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]